# How to give Permission to .sh file that I am downloading from net and executing through some other language?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu, file-permissions, permission-denied

I am downloading a file .sh file from my Jenkins then I am executing that file through some flow with command ./xyz.sh
But it is showing permission denied

Comment: `chmod +x ./xyz.sh`

Comment: Or run it as `sh ./xyz.sh`, then you don't need execute permission.

Comment: I am using arrays in shell script if I run with sh then it shows error

Comment: Can I give Permission and execution in one line?

Comment: `chmod +x ./xyz.sh; ./xyz.sh`

Comment: Use `bash` instead of `sh` if you need bash extensions.

Comment: thanks it solved my problem